# Replace GIF with other when animation ends

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a logo with some animated gifs with transparency. I want them to play when the other stops.

I have some letters as a logo in the background, and I want the gifs to play on top of it.

I tried with a slideshow script: the problem is that the duration of each gif is different, so if I put 10s for the gif to change, then the short ones will loop till the time is up.

i also tried making a CSS animation but it didn't work either, and I don't know why.

I haven't add transparency to the background of one of the gifs I used yet.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function() {
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
        .next('img').fadeIn()
        .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    },
    10000);
});
```

```css
#logo img {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

html {
  background-color: black;
}

.fadein {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%
}

.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">
  <div class="fadein">
    <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xiqR0MRajmJHWAUp3C/giphy.gif">
    <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/27IQkS7saXLTviuGH1/giphy.gif">
  </div>
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/1YcDQj7GctoBOIw22z/giphy.gif" alt="LOGO" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've understod you correct, you got one logo as a background to have two different overlay effects looping in their own timeline which I've calculated to be about ~4450 to ~5500 millisecondss and ~18000 milliseconds. Using `setInterval` with a `setTimeout` should work. However, I'd suggest you do add those effects onto one single gif animation, however, you may do it by the browser, it doesn't matter unless you'd decide to look for web browser compability. This is what I've done for you, bywhat I've understod of your help request:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div#logo img#overlayEffect").attr("src", "https://media.giphy.com/media/xiqR0MRajmJHWAUp3C/giphy.gif?" + (new Date()).getTime());
 setTimeout(function(){
   $("div#logo img#overlayEffect").attr("src", "https://i.giphy.com/media/27IQkS7saXLTviuGH1/giphy.gif?" + (new Date()).getTime());
 }, 5500);
  
  setInterval(function(){
   $("div#logo img#overlayEffect").attr("src", "https://media.giphy.com/media/xiqR0MRajmJHWAUp3C/giphy.gif?" + (new Date()).getTime());
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("div#logo img#overlayEffect").attr("src", "https://i.giphy.com/media/27IQkS7saXLTviuGH1/giphy.gif?" + (new Date()).getTime());
    }, 5500);
  }, 24000);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

div#logo {
  background: transparent url('https://media.giphy.com/media/1YcDQj7GctoBOIw22z/giphy.gif');
  width: 480px;
  height: 80px;
  
  /*just for a center*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /*these are /NOT/ required.*/
}

div#logo img#overlayEffect {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">
  <img id="overlayEffect" />
</div>
```

Comment: In a few hours i'm going to try if it works foe me. But i dont just want to add 2 gifs, I have already 5 of different lenghts each other, and i wanted to add more in the future. So: i have to make a function for each one saying how many time it will be showing and then the time it wont show (that it must be the duration of all other gifs together).